# Dependent scheduled SQL queries in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-warehouse

We have a data pipeline with ELT in BigQuery. We have several transformations. Some of those transformations depend on other transformations happening before.

With BigQuery scheduled queries we can only set a time, so either a lot of time the system is idle if we have large buffers, or when dependent scheduled queries are too near to each other, they overlap. How would one model a transformation pipeline in BigQuery with dependencies?

[Edit] I know about external tools like AirFlow but would like to use only Google services.

Comment: I recommend using some workflow orchestrator like airflow to manage your transformations. You can create the dependency between queries easily, not by time.

Comment: Check out **Magnus** - **Workflow Automator**. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).  Yet, another tool in this suite is **Goliath** - the **IDE for BigQuery**.  Disclosure: I am creator of those tools and leader on Potens team.

Comment: Thanks, I know about airflow, but would like to have a simple solution as possible.

Answer (score 0):

We can use workflow orchestrator solutions like Composer Airflow(Costly) or Cloud serverless workflows to manage the dependencies and the time of execution.